# Why doesn't this search work in SharePoint Foundation 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search

I am searching for a document in SharePoint Foundation 2010 and none of my searches pull up the document, even though it seems like they should.

In the SharePoint Document Library, the document name is listed is "What caseload can we deliver" and its author is listed as Smith, John. The document is presently checked in. When the document is opened, Document Properties - Server says its location is "C:\Users\jsmith\AppData\Local\Temp\What caseload can we deliver.pptx" and its author is Smith, John.  Yet none of the following searches retrieve the file,

filename:caseload
author:jsmith
author:smith
filetype:pptx

I believe the author generated this document from another PowerPoint document that was on SharePoint and renamed it, but the searches should still access the document properties above, right?
Any suggestions on a search that would pull up this document?

Comment: Make sure it is checked in so that the search engine can index it

Comment: First of all, do you find the doc if you search for only `caseload`? That would mean the doc is/is not in the search index.

Comment: Edited to note that document is checked in yet not found in search

Comment: Search for 'caseload' doesn't pull it up, so doc is not in the search index. How do I add it to the search index (I am just a regular user)? Doc was created by copying/renaming another doc which *is* in the search index; could SharePoint see them as the same doc even though they are in different libraries with different names/authors? If so what is workaround?